# Cannot use CheckBox in UserControl missing FORM Tag (ASPX)

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, controls

how do I use a  within an UserControl?
I always get the error, that the CheckBox should be placed within a FormTag (with runat=server), which is still existing on the MasterPage and it is not allowed to have two of them ...

Code of UserControl:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ctrlOrderEmailsDialog.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebClient.Controls.ctrlOrderEmailsDialog" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" TagPrefix="telerik" %>

<div id="OrderEmailDialog" runat="server">
    <table id="OrderEmailDialogTable">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Nr.</th>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="labelId" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>ReturnReceipt:</th>
                <td>
                    <%--<telerik:RadButton ID="checkboxReturnReceipt" runat="server" ToggleType="CustomToggle" ButtonType="ToggleButton" AutoPostBack="false">
                        <ToggleStates>
                            <telerik:RadButtonToggleState Text="UnChecked" PrimaryIconCssClass="rbToggleCheckbox"></telerik:RadButtonToggleState>
                            <telerik:RadButtonToggleState Text="Filled" PrimaryIconCssClass="rbToggleCheckboxFilled"
                                Selected="true"></telerik:RadButtonToggleState>
                            <telerik:RadButtonToggleState Text="Checked" PrimaryIconCssClass="rbToggleCheckboxChecked"></telerik:RadButtonToggleState>
                        </ToggleStates>
                    </telerik:RadButton>--%>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="checkboxReturnReceipt" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Mailtext:</th>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="OrderEmailText" runat="server">
                    </asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Form Tag (already existing within the SiteMaster page):

```
<form id="MainForm" runat="server">
```

System.Web.HttpException:
"The control ctrlOrderEmailsDialog_checkboxReturnReceipt type CheckBox must be positioned in a form tag with runat = server." which is existing ...

Can you guys give me a small hint?
Thank you.

//SiL

Comment: Can you show your user control code ?

Comment: Where exactly have you placed this User Control?

Comment: SiteMaster >> TabsControl >> Tab >> ctrlOrderEmails >> ctrlOrderEmailsDialog. As control for a RadWindow

Comment: For the meanwhile <input type="checkbox" runat="server"> does the job ... Somewhat strange with <asp:CheckBox> ...